# Asp.Net MVC/jQuery tools overlay: How to close it in an ajax return

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery, jquery-tools

I've an Ajax form in the popup I display with your overlay. I submit the  popup through ajax, and I need to close the overlay IF the ajax call has been successfull.

Here is currently my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Handle form submit ...
        $("#AddVariableForm").live("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#AddVariableForm');
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: "POST",
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.Success){
                        $("#adm-form-addVariable").data("overlay").close();
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Error '" + jqXhr.status + "' (textStatus: '" + textStatus + "', errorThrown: '" + errorThrown + "')");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    alert('complete');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

The problem is that it currently don't close anything. I double checked with chrome debug mode, it comes in the method but don't do anything. I also checked, no JS errors.

I tried to do the

```
$("#adm-form-addVariable").overlay({ api: true }).close()
```

but same problem.

Here is how I declare it:

```
   $(".adm-btn-overlay-trigger[rel]").overlay(
        {
            mask: {
                color: '#111',
                loadSpeed: 300,
                opacity: 0.9
            },

            closeOnClick: true
        }
    );
```

If I do this:

> $("#adm-form-addVariable").overlay({ api: true }).isOpened()

I get an undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to call close on the trigger element, not the overlay:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fwzwc/2/

In your case `$(".adm-btn-overlay-trigger[rel]").overlay().close();`

*Disclaimer:* I've never used jquery tools before, but as you see in my js fiddle, it seems to work.

Update: to make this work with multiple triggers you seem to need to find the exact trigger that opened the overlay. See http://jsfiddle.net/Fwzwc/3/ for an example for this.

It boils down to finding the id of the overlay div and then call .overlay().close() on the trigger where rel=overlayId:

```
$("img[rel='#" + overlayId + "']").overlay().close();
```

Comment: I tried and it works. I'm trying to understand why? Isn't [rel] a property accessor ? It's an xpath expression right? It may explain why I didn't understood before. PS: What an amazing tools jsfiddle is!!!! I didn't know before!!! Don't hesitate to forward me this kind of tools :) Huge fan :)

Comment: The jQuery expression basically says: "elements of class .adm-btn-overlay-trigger that have the rel attribute". jquery tools seems to store the information about overlays with the trigger, not with the overlay element itself. It's a design choice. BTW, my initial solution doesn't work with multiple triggers, as $(".adm-btn-overlay-trigger[rel]") can return multiple results. I updated my answer with a solution that does work.

Comment: Oh, and I just learned about jsfiddler recently here on SO. A nice tool indeed!